# Watson Discovery collection query

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'm trying to query my Watson Discovery collection through Java API using a natural language query.

The following code gives me this error:

*@JsonAdapter value must be TypeAdapter or TypeAdapterFactory reference.*

I tried to query the collection with Postman, using the same collection, user, password and environment feature and it works fine.

```
Discovery discovery = new Discovery("2018-08-01","myUsername","myPwd");
discovery.setEndPoint("myEndpoint");
String environmentId = "myEnvironment";
String collectionId = "myCollection";
QueryOptions.Builder queryBuilder = new QueryOptions.Builder(environmentId, collectionId);
queryBuilder.naturalLanguageQuery(myQueryString)
            .deduplicate(false)
            .highlight(true)
            .passages(true)
            .passagesCount(5);
QueryResponse queryResponse = discovery.query(queryBuilder.build());
queryResponse.execute();
```

In my project I also use other services which works on the same Liberty Server and I have not any kind of problem.

P.S.: all dependencies are set and VCAP_SERVICES string is written ad hoc.